# Feathersjs VS Senecajs

Tags: node.js, feathersjs, seneca

I've been playing with Seneca microservice and feathersjs. Both share some level of similarities. I tried the examples of both seneca and feathers.
Feathers has few advantages like

- Simple and nice CLI Generator
- Hooks
- Nice Documentation.

And the drawback is it's coupled with Express. it should be independent like Seneca.

Below is the code of simple example using Seneca. it's run on different ports and seems like all services are independent to each other. Seneca is more like independent. I also found one amazing repository on git [Ramanujan](https://github.com/senecajs/ramanujan).

I want to know the advantages and disadvantages of both. It's really bad to compare both but my goal is to use one of them to make API.

So I'm quite confused about which one to choose.

**server.js**

```
seneca.add({cmd: 'config'}, function (msg, done) {
  var config = {rate: 0.23}
  var value = config[msg.prop]
  done(null, {value: value})
})

// local rates
seneca.add({cmd: 'salestax', country: 'US'}, function (msg, done) {
  var state = {
    'NY': 0.04,
    'CA': 0.0625
    // ...
  }
  var rate = state[msg.state]
  var total = msg.net * (1 + rate)
  done(null, {total: total})
})
.listen({"type": "http", "port": 10101});


// categories
seneca.add({ cmd: 'salestax', country: 'IE' }, function (msg, done) {
  var category = {
    'top': 0.23,
    'reduced': 0.135
    // ...
  }
  var rate = category[msg.category]
  var total = msg.net * (1 + rate)
  done(null, { total: total })
})
.listen({"type": "http", "port": 10102});

//normal
seneca.add({cmd: 'salestax'}, function (msg, done) {
  seneca.act({cmd: 'config', prop: 'rate'}, function (err, result) {
    var rate  = parseFloat(result.value)
    var total = msg.net * (1 + rate)
    done(null, {total: total})
  })
})
.listen({"type": "http", "port": 10103});
```

**client.js**

```
require('seneca')()
  .client( {port: 10101} )
  .client( {port: 10102} )
  .client( {port: 10103} )

  .ready( function () {
      this.act('cmd:salestax,net:100,country:IE,category:reduced', function (err, result) {
        console.log('IE: ' + result.total)
      })
      this.act('cmd:salestax,net:100,country:US,state:NY', function (err, result) {
        console.log('US,NY: ' + result.total)
      })
      this.act('cmd:salestax,net:100,country:DE', function (err, result) {
        console.log('DE: ' + result.total)
      })
      this.act('cmd:salestax,net:100', function (err, result) {
        console.log(result.total)
      })
  })
```

Comment: Although this question will probably be closed since it is mostly opinion based it's probably worth pointing out that the next version of Feathers will be framework independent (with very little breaking changes required to upgrade from the current). You can read more about this at https://blog.feathersjs.com/after-auk-whats-next-for-feathers-buzzard-c68358a3e62f

Comment: Thanks a lot @Daff.

Comment: Great article indeed, next version of feathers would be a revolutionary. I would like to know more about Seneca too.